# How to restore programmatically changed LayoutParams after configuration changes

Tags: android, textview, layoutparams

Say the textsize of a textview defined in the layout file is 12sp, I dynamically changed it to 24sp .but When I rotate the screen, the textsize will change back to 12sp. Is there anyway to retain the LayoutParams that is set at run time when configuration changes?

Comment: You have to use `SavedInstance` or `SharedPreference` whichever suits your purpose best.

Comment: Read this for more details -> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi user3591494 you can save and restore your text size with android. Add below code to your activity.

```
private final String TEXT_SIZE_KEY = "text_size";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // save text view size
    savedInstanceState.putFloat(TEXT_SIZE_KEY, yourTextView.getTextSize());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Then restore your textSize after your activity restores like this

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // restore your text size and set to your text view
    float textSize = savedInstanceState.getFloat(TEXT_SIZE_KEY);
    yourTextView.setTextSize(textSize);
}
```

Hi again, sorry answer to your comment is too big to be posted. The approach will be same. So when u call linearLayout.LayoutParams(0,MATCH_PARENT, 1f)) if you hover on the function you'll see what your calling is linearLayout.LayoutParams(int, int, float) the parameters being width, height and weight. So using the same approach store the 3 values in bundle using savedInstanceState.putInt(FRAME_A_WIDTH, yourLayout.getLayoutParams().width) and restore it using the same approach in onRestoreInstanceState() function. Instead of calling yourTextView.setTextSize(textSize) on your text view just call setLayoutParams on your view with restored values. Let me know if you need code snippet for this question, post your xml & i'll add it above.

Comment: what if it's not textsize. what if it's the width of height of a view.Say there'r e two framelayouts in a LinearLayout. say framelayout1 and framelayout2.the width and height of  framelayout1 are both MATCH_PARENT, the width of framelayout2 is 0 and height is MATCH_PARENT.I change LayoutParams of the two framelayouts programmatically: FrameLayout1.setLayoutParams(new linearLayout.LayoutParams(0,MATCH_PARENT, 1f));  
FrameLayout2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,MATCH_PARENT, 2f));
how can I restore the LayoutParams when I rotate the screen.

Comment: Hi user3591494, i updated my answer comment is too long to be posted as per stacks limits.